# Displaying different content on a Profile page when the logged-in user is the Profile owner

Tags: php, html, profile

I always try to make code nicer and more maintainable but I'm not sure if I do it right... For example, I'm doing a social network site, so the page domain.com/profile?id=17 would open profile for user id 17. If the user is the currently logged in one, then the profile will be seen as the owner (with edit options, etc) otherwise the page would show a profile for outsiders (no edit options).

How do I do this nicely? I was thinking that after checking if the user id == the user id in $_SESSION, I include one php file (the one with the edit options), otherwise I include the other one. Is this a solution? Is there a better one?

I do the same thing for headers, I have a file 'header.php' that includes the header of all pages (some php but also a logo, etc), however I'm not sure if this is good since a user can go to his browser and type mydomain.com/header.php and then be displayed a header only.

Comment: You were thinking correctly. There is too much to tell in a simple answer, but why not look at a few popular open-source projects? You could learn a lot from the sourcecode of a CMS, forum or wiki. Most have blogs too which explain the rationale behind certain decisions. Even stackoverflow has a pretty nice blog.

Comment: Seems to broad of a question to have a single correct answer. I vote for community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is one way to do it .another way to do it would e just check the user_id in session and if it is not set then just display another html . Also you would want to access users as their usernames rather than user id.For example instead of user_id.php=17 to username/luqita.If you are using apache as the web server then you could use it's mod_rewite module to generate pretty urls.

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to change his URLs at all.. It sounds like he just wants to display different content based on whether or not the user viewing the page is the owner of that account.

Comment: I know how to display different contents I just don't know how to do it